# polymorphic kotlinx serialization fails on object after obfuscation

Tags: proguard, kotlinx.serialization

i have a polymorphic type that is implemented by objects and classes.

```kotlin
sealed interface Base 

@Serializable
@SerialName("Sub")
class Sub(...) : Base

@Serializable
@SerialName("Obj")
object Obj : Base
```

i use this type with kotlinx.serialization

```kotlin
polymorphic(Base::class) {
  subclass(Sub::class)
  subclass(Obj::class)
}
```

this runs when there is no obfuscation, but when obfuscation is turned on, i get:
`Serializer for class 'Obj' is not found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.`

my proguard configuration regarding `kotlinx.serialization` is

```
-keepclassmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    *** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class .** {
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

-keep,includedescriptorclasses class my.package.**$$serializer { *; }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make proguard keep kotlinx serializers for objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663076/how-to-make-proguard-keep-kotlinx-serializers-for-objects)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the generated serializer is different for objects and classes.
while in classes it is `Sub$serializer` in objects it is `Obj$defaultSerializer$delegate`, which slips through the Proguard rules.

While a good solution would be changing the Proguard rules to catch this case,

a usefull hack is to pass the serializer directly, instead of letting the `polymorphic` builder find it by the class.

```kotlin
polymorphic(Base::class) {
  ..
  subclass(Obj.serializer())
}
```

Comment: can you please take a look on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73064940/11560810)