# How to make proguard keep kotlinx serializers for objects?

Tags: proguard, kotlinx.serialization

i have a kotlin class and an object

```kotlin
@Serializable
@SerialName("Cl")
class Cl(...)

@Serializable
@SerialName("Obj")
object Obj
```

and my proguard is configured like this

```
-keepclassmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    *** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class .** {
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

-keep,includedescriptorclasses class my.package.**$$serializer { *; }
```

but, while the serializer of the class is kept, the serializer of the object is not.
here is the mapping of the class:

```
Cl -> Cl:
...
    ...
    67:67:void <init>(... ,kotlinx.serialization.internal.SerializationConstructorMarker) -> <init>
    70:75:void <init>(...) -> <init>
    67:67:void write$Self(Cl,kotlinx.serialization.encoding.CompositeEncoder,kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor) -> e
Cl$$serializer -> Cl$$serializer:
...
    67:75:void <clinit>() -> <clinit>
    67:67:void <init>() -> <init>
    67:67:kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer[] childSerializers() -> childSerializers
    67:67:Cl deserialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder) -> deserialize
    67:67:java.lang.Object deserialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder) -> deserialize
    67:67:void serialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder,Cl) -> serialize
    67:67:void serialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder,java.lang.Object) -> serialize
    67:67:kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer[] typeParametersSerializers() -> typeParametersSerializers
Cl$Companion -> Cl$Companion:
...
    67:67:void <init>() -> <init>
    67:67:kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer() -> serializer
```

and here is the mapping of the object:

```
Obj -> Obj:
...
    Obj INSTANCE -> n
    kotlin.Lazy $cachedSerializer$delegate -> o
    ...
    47:47:kotlin.Lazy get$cachedSerializer$delegate() -> e
    47:47:kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer() -> serializer
Obj$$cachedSerializer$delegate$1 -> Obj$a:
...
    Obj$$cachedSerializer$delegate$1 INSTANCE -> l
    47:47:kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer invoke() -> a
    47:47:java.lang.Object invoke() -> m
...
```

this obfuscation causes a crash (only when obfuscated, only for object) when using:

```kotlin
polymorphic(...) {
  subclass(Obj::class)
}
```

`Serializer for class 'Obj' is not found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.`

How can i tell Proguard to keep the serializer for `object`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is documentation available [on how to configure ProGuard](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#android), which does not seem to match the configuration you are using.

Use that and you should be good to go.

Purely informational, since the above already answers your question: serializer lookup at runtime for `object` is different and happens through `INSTANCE`. The relevant part from the docs.

```
# Keep `INSTANCE.serializer()` of serializable objects.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class ** {
    public static ** INSTANCE;
}
-keepclassmembers class <1> {
    public static <1> INSTANCE;
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}
```